# Грамматический род в современном русском - каковы веяния?

Tags: грамматика, род

Вопрос к специалистам, кто в теме. Расскажите кратко о перспективах рода (гендера) в русском. Что предлагают лингвисты на перспективу, о чем спорят?

Вот, например, два варианта:

1) Строгая учительница Елена поставила двойку.

2) Строгий учитель Елена поставила двойку.

Вариант 1 явно уходит в прошлое, т.к. женские и мужские формы одного и того же существительного (профессии, например), как кажется, анахронизм.

Вариант 2 разбивает подлежащее "учитель Елена": учитель согласуеся по роду с "строгий", а Елена с "поставила". Этот вариант сталкивается с трудностью, если мы не упоминаем имени Елена, хотя *знаем*, что речь идет о женщине. Тогда:

Вариант а) Строгий учитель поставила двойку

Вариант б) Строгий учитель поставил двойку

Должны ли мы игнорировать (известный) пол субъекта, если он нерелевантен содержанию? Это не только языковый, но и политический вопрос. Вариант (б) кажется достаточно приемлемым (и политкорректным), но сталкивается с непривычной нескладицей вот в такой конструкции с заминкой:

Строгий учитель, Елена, поставил двойку.

Вариант в) Строгая учитель поставила двойку - очевидно никак неприемлем: учитель муж. гр. рода.

Если учитель "строгий", то кто "поставил(а)" двойку: учитель (тогда поставил), или Елена (тогда поставила)? Семантически, скорее учитель, но синтаксически (или по чистой смежности), скорее Елена. И если взять вариант (а), то как расставить род при таком изменении порядка:

Строгий? -ая? Елена-учитель поставил? -а? двойку

Словом, как быть? И что говорят эксперты на эти темы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Строгая учительница Елена поставила двойку.
2) Строгий учитель Елена поставила двойку. Оба варианта корректны,никакого анахронизма нет.

```
     Вариант 2 разбивает подлежащее "учитель Елена": учитель согласуется
  по роду с "строгий", а Елена с "поставила".
```

Подлежащее здесь Елена (что сделала?) поставила двойку - всё нормально. Елена есть кто по профессии? -строгий учитель - это несогласованное приложение. Тоже всё нормально.

а) Строгий учитель поставила двойку - разговорный вариант.

б) Строгий учитель поставил двойку - норма

1.Многие имена сущ. муж. рода, обозначающие лицо по профессии, занимаемой должности, выполняемой работе, занятию, ученому или почетному званию и т.д., 
 **в литературном языке** сохраняют свою форму и в тех случаях, когда относятся к лицам женского пола, например: педагог, техник, токарь, геолог, физик, металлург, конструктор, оператор, новатор, судья, адвокат, доцент, кандидат наук, депутат, Герой Российской Федерации, лауреат международного конкурса, мастерспорта, полковник, лейтенант.

В **разговорной** речи явно наметилась тенденция выражать отнесение подобных слов к лицам женского пола с и н т а к с и ч е с к и, главным образом путем постановки сказуемого в форме женского рода, если в функции подлежащего выступает одно из слов указанной группы, например: депутат принимала посетителей, мастер спорта установила новый мировой рекорд, оператор хорошо справилась с заданием.

Такие сочетания встречаются и в тех случаях, когда имеется возможность образовать парное название женского рода, но с известными стилистическими ограничениями, например: секретарь выдала справку, редактор была в декретном отпуске.

Встречаются подобные конструкции и в художественной литературе – в речи персонажей и в авторской речи, например: Военфельдшер добросовестна, не больше (В. Панова); По-видимому, приисковый счетовод серьёзно заболела (А. Коптяева); Агроном уехала в район (Антонов).

2.В нейтральных стилях речи параллельные названия для обозначения лиц женского пола закрепились в тех случаях, когда данная специальность в равной мере связана и с женским и с мужским трудом, например: акушер – акушерка, буфетчик – буфетчица, лаборант – лаборантка, лётчик – лётчица, преподаватель – преподавательница, продавец – продавщица, студент – студентка, ткач – ткачиха, тракторист – трактористка, учитель – учительница, артист – артистка, писатель – писательница, спортсмен – спортсменка. Но **в официально-деловом стиле** предпочтительно сохранять форму мужского рода,  в документе-справке: «Е. А. Шишкова работает лаборантом на кафедре физики» (в обиходной речи лаборантка Шишкова)

Использование парного образования женского рода устраняет неясность в тех случаях, когда нерусская фамилия не позволяет установить, идет ли речь о мужчине или о женщине, например: Корреспондентка газеты М. Смит сообщает… (а не корреспондент, так как подобные фамилии не связаны с реальным полом их носителя).

Иногда образованию парного названия мешает то, что подобное название уже  употребляется с другим значением. Так, к слову овчар нельзя было образовать параллельное название «овчарка» (по модели дояр– доярка), поскольку это слово уже закрепилось как название породы собак.

3.В разговорной речи встречаются парные названия, образованные при помощи суффиксов -ша и -иха, например: библиотекарша, билетёрша, бухгалтерша, директорша, докторша, инженерша, кассирша, комендантша, кондукторша; врачиха, дворничиха, сторожиха.  Однако подобные образования используются ограниченно. Их распространению препятствует, с одной стороны, присущая им двузначность: они могут быть поняты как название жены человека соответствующей профессии и как название действующего лица: ср. Вот идет наша бригадирша (то ли жена бригадира, то ли сама бригадир); Дворничиха помогает нам по хозяйству (та же двузначность).  Раньше названия с суффиксами -ша и -иха обозначали наименования жен по мужу: генеральша, губернаторша, дьячиха, купчиха и т. п.

С другой стороны, в литературной речи подобных образований избегают из-за **просторечного**, сниженного, иногда пренебрежительного оценочного значения (профессорша, врачиха). Особенно это относится к словам на -иха; возможно, что здесь сказываются нежелательные ассоциации с названиями животных (ср. заяц – зайчиха, слон – слониха и т. п.). Сказанное не относится к закрепившимся в языке нейтральным словам типа портниха, ткачиха. В **профессиональной** речи свободно используются слова спринтерша, пловчиха.

Для обозначения мужского соответствия словам балерина, машинистка используются описательные выражения: артист балета, переписчик на машинке. В профессиональном употреблении возникла пара медицинская сестра – медицинский брат.

Какой род получает прилагательное при имени директор или инженер? Прилагательное (и местоимение) при существительном данной группы получает форму мужского рода: главный инженер Круглова, наш судья Терехова, участковый врач Горина, научный руководитель Сомова, мой директор Лазарева. Но глагол при существительном рассматриваемой группы употребляется в женском роде: Секретарь Петрова выдала справку. Бухгалтер Крымова подписала ведомость.

Таким образом, синтаксис предложения, содержащего имена группы "профессия – должность", может выглядеть следующим образом: Мой научный руководитель (Сомова) сделала замечания; Наш коммерческий директор (Потапова) подписала документы; Мой участковый врач (Горина) открыла бюллетень.

Можно обозначить род в виде сложных слов:женщина-директор, девушка-секретарь.

Конструкции типа врач пришла, молодая врач стали достаточно распространенными в разговорной речи. Впервые такое употребление было отмечено А.М. Пешковским как согласование "по смыслу", однако оно имеет место только в им. падеже при невозможности других падежей: молодой врача, молодой врачу и т.д., и это препятствует включению подобных лексем в состав существительных общего рода, хотя известна точка зрения проф. И.Г. Милославского о том, что слова такого типа "тяготеют к существительным общего рода", они "кандидаты" в слова общего рода, однако вряд ли это произойдет в ближайшее время.
https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/222/%D0%A

Comment: Если правда 'учитель Елена' это не двойное подлежащее, а дополнение+подлежащее, то это снимает проблему сразу. В "Учитель, Елена, поставил двойку. Он мог бы быть менее строгим" корректно, не так ли? - ведь тут подлежащее 'учитель'?

Comment: Это не дополнение, а ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ - особый вид определения, выраженный сущ., второе название. Учитель, Елена, поставил двойку - вполне корректна грамматика, согласование в роде, но само предложение неестественное, на иностранный манер, как-то не соответствует ни одному стилю. Если в р.языке есть параллельная по роду пара, нужно употреблять сущ. жен.рода. Если это деловой стиль(объяснительная), то должно быть: "Учительница, Елена Ивановна Иванова, поставила эту двойку..." Или: "Елена Ивановна, учитель первого класса, поставила..." Если  разгов. стиль, то учитель Елена Ив. поставила.

Comment: Людмила, большое спасибо за разъяснение.